# Finding the Control associated with ASP.NET validator using JQUERY or simple Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, server-side-validation

I've a page with few textboxes and their corresponding validators (ASP.NET validator).

And clearly I can validate each of those validators from javascript by calling the function

```
Page_ClientValidate("myvalidators")
```

where myvalidators is my validators group name

The same way I can validate a specific validator using

```
ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[0]);
```

which only checks that specific validator

But my question is how can I find or figure out the control (Textbox) which is connected with that specific validator.

That means a function which can return all the controls with a failed validator.

Or more clearly, the function should return a collection object of controls where there corespnding validator is failed.

**More description added**

My scenario is to highlight the parent div  of the textbox where the validator failed. So if I get the texbox control object or the control arrays, I can just take each of its parent div and can highlight it.

Comment: Showing the generated html will make it quite easy to understand

Comment: @Adil Does it require? Coz I specified the function I used to invoke the validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page_Validators array returns the same metadata that we receive in custom validation function. It means that you can receive the associated control identifier something like this `Page_Validators[0].controltovalidate`.

```
 <script>
$(function () {
  // process all validators and their controls
  $.each(Page_Validators,function (i,v){ 
     if(v.controltovalidate) { 
        $("#"+v.controltovalidate); 
     } 
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry.. I think you misunderstood my scenario... 
Actually my requirement is, imagine my textbox id is txt1 and there is a requirefield validator assosiated with it. That validator I can refer as Page_Validators[0]
So what my question is how we can get that txt1 object from using this reference Page_Validators[0]?
Hope its clear now

Comment: Try this $("#"+Page_Validators[0].controltovalidate)

Comment: Thats awesome friend... Worked like a charm.. If you replace this with the answer given, I can mark it as right answer...

Comment: Ok. I replaced the answer